# How did online training work in the Word2vec model using Genism

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

Using the Genism library, we can load the model and update the vocabulary when the new sentence will be added. That’s means If you save the model you can continue training it later. I checked with sample data, let’s say I have a word in my vocabulary that was previously trained (i.e. “women”). And after that let’s say I have new sentences and using model.build_vocab(new_sentence, update=True) and model.train(new_sentence), the model is updated. Now, in my new_sentence I have some word that already exists(“women”) in the previous vocabulary list and have some new word(“girl”) that not exists in the previous vocabulary list. After updating the vocabulary, I have both old and new words in the corpus. And I checked using model.wv[‘women’], the vector is updated after update and training new sentence. Also, get the word embedding vector for a new word i.e. model.wv[‘girl’]. All other words that were previously trained and not in the new_sentence, those word vectors not changed.

```
model = Word2Vec(old_sentences, vector_size=100,window=5, min_count=1) 
model.save("word2vec.model")
model = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model") //load previously save model 
model.build_vocab(new_sentences,update=True,total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)   
model.train(new_sentences)
```

However, just don’t understand the inside depth explanation of how the online training is working. Please let me know if anybody knows in detail. I get the code but want to understand how the online training working in theoretically. Is it re-train the model on the old and new training data from scratch?

Here is the link that I followed: [Online training](https://rutumulkar.com/blog/2015/word2vec/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a new call to `.train()`, it only trains on the new data. So only words in the new data can possibly be updated.

And to the extent that the new data may be smaller, and more idiosyncratic in its word usages, any words in the new data will be trained to only be consistent with other words being trained in the new data. (Depending on the size of the new data, and the training parameters chosen like `alpha` & `epochs`, they might be pulled via the new examples arbitrarily far from their old locations - and thus start to lose comparability to words that were trained earlier.)

(Note also that when providing an different corpus that the original, you shouldn't use a parameter like `total_examples=model.corpus_count`, reusing `model.corpus_count`, a value cahced in the model from the earlier data. Rather, parameters should describe the current batch of data.)

Frankly, I'm not a fan of this feature. It's possible it could be useful to advanced users. But most people drawn to it are likely misuing it, expecting any number of tiny incremental updates to constantly expand & improve the model - when there's no good support for the idea that will reliably happen with naive use.

In fact, there's reasons to doubt such updates are generally a good idea. There's even an established term for the risk that incremental updates to a neural-network wreck its prior performance: [catastrophic forgetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference).

The straightforward & best-grounded approach to updating word-vectors for new expanded data is to re-train from scratch, so all words are on equal footing, and go through the same interleaved training, on the same unified optimization (SGD) schedule. (The new new vectors at the end of such a process will not be in a compatible coordinate space, but should be equivalently useful, or better if the data is now bigger and better.)

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I didn't choose Alpha, on the genism site it recommended not to chose Alpha by yourself. It was mentioned, "Use only if making multiple calls to train(), when you want to manage the alpha learning-rate yourself (not recommended)". I am not sure what does mean the multiple calls to train(). Also about the total_examples=model.corpus_count, you are right. I tested with my dataset, and every time by retraining the model with new_sentences, the words that were previously present in vocabulary, the word vector changed.

Comment: With this approach, when you do the initial training on `old_sentence`, you are essentially calling `train()` a 1st time, using the default `alpha`/`epochs` - so far, so good. Bu then when calling `train()` again, on the new data, you're (implicitly) choosing to use the default `alpha` & `epochs` again - which might or might not be a good idea anymore, with a new subset of data, that might be smaller than the original. The standard optimization happening behind the scenes, SGD,  generally assumes one session, over all data, gradually decaying the `alpha` learning rate.

Comment: When you then repeat the SGD process, but now with some overlapping data, and some words (that were already optimized with regard to, and in balance with, the old data/co-occurring words) are now getting new training updates again at a high alpha after already being runed wiht a low-alpha, you're now in improvised hybrid territory. It might still be helpful! But it's no longer as clearly balanced as the "one session" standard approach, with some words getting several full high-alpha-to-low-alpha sessions with different subsets of data, & others getting only one on data last seen long ago.

Comment: So the number of things that can go wrong are higher, & the number of non-default choices that must be made with advanced understanding increase, & the need to double-check that resuklts may have gotten worse becomes stronger - in general, a higher-risk set of steps.

Comment: I understand. I was following your comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51135118/gensim-word2vec-freeze-some-wordvectors-and-update-others. Freeze the word that already trained would be a solution for me. However, this functionality not implemented yet. I am thinking to fork the repository and update the file. Although I am totally in dark, when I looked in word2vec.py file.  self.wv.vectors_lockf = np.ones(1, dtype=REAL), how can I set 0.0 for some word that I want to freeze. Please suggest me how can I go through this.

Comment: As the comment in the source notes: `# EXPERIMENTAL lockf feature; create minimal no-op lockf arrays (1 element of 1.0)` & `# advanced users should directly resize/adjust as desired after any vocab growth`. You'll have to change the size of that array to match your vocabulary size, & then put `0.0` values where you want training suppressed. But essentially, if you're asking for guidance on how to use this feature, then using it is a bad idea - it's there for advanced experimentation, & whether it can actually be helpful is unproven & would require a lot of analysis.

Comment: Can you please suggest any other word embedding method/technique that allows incrementally updating the model? The main confusion started from the https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html, it says "If you save the model you can continue training it later". Also checked on doc2vec model in genism, it says "# you can continue training with the loaded model!". Thanks for all of your valuable comment.

Comment: I don't know of any off-the-shelf technique or library I can recommend, because it's not a task with a simple reliable standard approach. Are you sure you need to do incremental updates?

Comment: The main idea for my project is, I have data that will come almost every day and it will continue coming. I am working with abstract and text_body field for covid-19 related research paper that is publishing regularly. From the last release of data, I have nearly 500k paper and I can train the model with word2vec. However, for continuously adding the data(let's say one week data) in the model, I need incremental update. The main goal is similar paper cluster together.

Comment: Let's say whatever data I have so far I can do train my model and for the next release data I need to check the new data is most similar to the existing data group and assign the new data into that group. That's the reason need the incremental update, so that new data can add to the model. And for next run the new data and old data everything we can consider together.

Comment: After new data arrives, why not just re-train on the whole, now larger, dataset? It may take a little longer, but will almost certainly offer better results than some cobbled-together never-quite-proven-to-work incremental update approach.

Comment: yes, it will become larger, as I mentioned it will be on regular basis, training from the scratch will take longer time.

Comment: Yes, but how much larger/longer? Merely getting larger & more time-consuming isn't *necessarily* an adequate reason to introduce the process & quality complications of some improvised incremental update strategy. I would only try incremental if I was sure my computing resources couldn't achieve the goal in a more simple way. How long does the initial 500K docs training take? How many weeks/months/years will it be before there are 1M docs?

Comment: For 500k it took nearly 3hour to complete. Every week data get to increase by nearly 1000.

Comment: So, if it grows 1000 a week, in 500 more weeks - into the year 2031 - it will be 1M documents long. And, it might take 6 hours to run - so if launched automatically with all the old & new data, from scratch, each week at 10pm Sunday night, it'll be done by 4am Monday morning. (And maybe there are still ways to speed that up, or server speed will improve further between now and 2031.) Seriously, 3h-12h is still a pretty short training runtime, best executed overnight so you can be mostly indifferent to the runtime until/unless it gets much longer.